# Counter-example about paracompactness

Tags: general-topology

I am trying to find a counter-example related to the definition of paracompactness, but it seems that it is not very easy. Here is the problem.

> Give an example to show that if $X$ is paracompact, it does not follow that for every open covering $A$ of $X$, there is a locally finite subcollection of $A$ that covers $X$.

I think the Sorgenfrey line might work, because it is paracompact but not compact. But I can't find any open covering that satisfies the problem.

Comment: What if you gave $\Bbb Z$ the discrete metric and took the cover to consist of sets of the form $[-z,z]\cap\Bbb Z$, $z\in \Bbb Z$?

Comment: Oh, simple and quite right. We can take point $0$, right?$ 0$ belongs to every subset of that sort. Thanks so much.

Comment: The same basic idea works for the Sorgenfrey line $S$: if $\mathscr{U}$ is any subcover of $\{[n,\to):n\in\Bbb Z\}$, every open set is actually a subset of infinitely many members of $\mathscr{U}$. For that matter, you can just use $\Bbb R$: if $\mathscr{U}$ is a subcover of $\{(-n,n):n\in\Bbb Z^+\}$, every open set in $\Bbb R$ is contained in infinitely many members of $\mathscr{U}$. In both cases it’s clear that no subcover can be locally finite: every subcover is everywhere locally infinite!